# CakePHP hasMany_Through retrieve data from tableA and their tableB

Tags: cakephp, has-many-through

Please help me. I am new on CakePHP.
I have a database association.
Newsletter hasAndBelongsToMany Category.
I tried hasMany_Through in stead of hasAndBelongsToMany (HABTM)

```
//Newsletter
public $hasMany = array(
    'CategoryNewsletterShip'
    )
);



//Category
public $hasMany = array(
   'CategoryNewsletterShip'
       )
 );


//CategoryNewsletterShip
 public $belongsTo = array(
    'Newsletter', 'Category'
    )
 );
```

on NewsletterController I've tried: find('all') ;

```
// NewslettersConroller
$newsletters = $this->Newsletter->find('threaded');
this->set('newsletters', $newsletters);
//----
```

I can retrieve only Newsletters and their many CategoryNewsletterShips.
How do I retrieve their Categories ?

What i need is Newsletters and theirs Categories.

Thank for yours help.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late

you need to build a join query :

```
$this->Newsletter->find('all', array(
 'joins' => array(
                    array(
                        'table'         => 'category_newsletter_ships',
                        'alias'         => 'CategoryNewsletterShip',
                        'type'          => 'inner',
                        'conditions'    => array(
                            'Newsletter.id = CategoryNewsletterShip.newsletter_id'
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'table'         => 'categories',
                        'alias'         => 'Category',
                        'type'          => 'inner',
                        'conditions'    => array(
                            'Category.id = CategoryNewsletterShip.category_id'
                        ),
                    )
)));
```